How to create a network bridge between wlan0 and eth1 to connect a second eth0 device?

I have a network topology as described in the Network Setup image above.
I have a WiFi router on a private 10.12.12.1 network. An Ubuntu 20.04 box, on a Nvidia Jetson, is connected to a WiFi network with an IP address 10.12.12.z. The Nvidia Jetson has two physical eth0 and eth1 devices/cards. I would like to connect a Debian Box that has a physical eth0 interface to the eth1 interface on the Nvidia Jetson.
I am unclear on the networking terminology that is needed to achieve this Network Setup but I have started by bridging wlan0 and eth1 on the Ubuntu 20.04 using a netplan configuration as follows:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: no
      access-points:
        "******":
         password: "******"
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth1, wlan0]
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: no

I am unclear what my next steps should be after this point?
I assigned a static IP to the Debian box along with subnet, etc. At this point I cannot ping the Debian box from the Ubuntu box. Am I supposed to assign an IP address to the physical interface on the Ubuntu box? I did not think so because I thought the bridge basically makes the wlan0 and eth1 as a br0 device. Here are some outputs from bridge related commands:
CMD PROMPT>$ brctl show br0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.2046a10bbe78       yes             eth1


CMD PROMPT$> bridge link
    7: rndis0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 master l4tbr0 state disabled priority 32 cost 100
    8: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 master l4tbr0 state disabled priority 32 cost 100
    12: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100

It may be possible that I am mixing too many concepts from too many different dated threads. In some discussions I read bridging WiFi client not possible to ethx device. Other posts suggest configuring the WiFi interface to an Access Point (AP) so long as the WiFi device supports AP mode. Other posts suggest using NAT.
Another potential clarity that would help me is that Ubuntu automatically assigns 10.42.x.xx IP range to the ethx devices. Ideally, I would like our ISP/Router to just assign the IP addresses to the eth0/eth1 device via DHCP, via the bridge, rather than manually managing the static IPs from the individual devices would like to set the static assignment at the router.
I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction to sort this out.
